# Field belongs to a class, but how to use polymorphism

Tags: c#, oop, polymorphism

I have a method in a base class

```
class Base
{
   private static string Colour = "blue";
   string DoStuff() { return ColourProp; }

   protected virtual string ColourProp { get{ return Base.Colour; } }
}
```

that is called on an instance of this subclass

```
class Sub
{
   private static string Colour = "orange";

   protected override string ColourProp { get{ return Sub.Colour; } }
}
```

At the moment I'm using virtual properties, is this the only way? (considering that fields cannot be virtual)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you do need to use either a virtual property or a virtual method to accomplish this.  The  CLR will dynamically dispatch all calls to `ColourProp` correctly based on the type of the object (i.e. polymorphism).

Comment: yeah that's fine, but I was just wondering since ideally (for my problem) the Colour fields belong to the class and not the instance...maybe I can use reflection or something to call the type dynamically???

Comment: They may belong to the class, but you can't do polymorphism on static members, and no, using reflection to do this constitutes a "smell".  Maybe you could take a step back and describe what you're trying to achieve at a higher level?

Comment: Ok, I admit it's overkill and smelly to do this. I'm just wondering if there's a way to achieve polymorphism like behaviour with class variables (basically just to cut that extra property out of each subclass, so all I have to do is define a field and then this is used by the superclass).

Answer (score 0):

This looks totally fine. Don't worry about virtual properties. This provides not only an encapsulation of your data against other objects but also against subclasses.