# Can not access derived class fields using base class

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, ooad

I am not able to access simple field from derived class so what
is use of  polymorphism in case of fields. If I have to downcast to ResponseMBP to get the Name property then my client needs to know about derived class.

So does polymorphism work only for methods?

```
public abstract class Response
{
}

public class ResponseMbp : Response
{        
    public string Name = "My Name";        
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Response r = new ResponseMbp();
        Console.Write(r.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not downcasting to ResponseMBP, you are upcasting to it. Surely you cannot access members of derived class if you have a base class reference.

Comment: @Michael, Thanks for your reply. Are you sure about 'upcasting'? If I have to use ((ResponseMBP)Response).Name that means it is downcasting, doesn't it? Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524197/downcast-and-upcast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all for field polymorphism, you should have that field declared in both the base and derived class (as is the case with method polymorphism).

Now in you example, the field "name" is only part of derived class signature, and you do not have "name" variable in the signature of your base class. Due to this the object of your base class, though it is instantiated with derived class, would only show you base class signature items.
Thus due to this reason, you are not able to use r.name in your example.

To know proper usage of field polymorphism, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227403/field-belongs-to-a-class-but-how-to-use-polymorphism) link.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining your variable as type `Response`. At this point you can only access properties and variables that are contained in the `Response` class and its superclasses.

You're also trying to refer to `Name` while the property is named `name`.

Answer (score 0):

`ResponseMbp` is inheriting from `Response`. So `ResponseMbp` is a `Response`, but a `Response` is not a `ResponseMbp`.

Since you are defining the property `Name` in `ResponseMbp`, `Response` does not know, or care, about it.

If you defined `Name` in `Response`, `ResponseMbp` would inherit the property, and it would be accessible from either class.